# Having trouble with Unity + iOS + Amazon ads

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, bitcode

I have been stuck for hours. I recently implemented Amazon mobile ads to my unity project for my iOS application. I added the unity plugin and the framework for amazon ads in my unity project. I build for my iPhone and iPad and the Amazon ads work perfectly! But, when I go to archive the project in order to send it to Apple, I get a Mach-o linker error. It says that the amazonadoptions.o was built without using bitcode. I tried disabling bitcode but that made more errors. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong. I would greatly appreciate any opinions on what I'm missing. Thanks guys!

Comment: What's the deployment target?  The bitcode stuff is fairly recent and I *thought* the default unity deployment target was fairly old, so the linker shouldn't be worrying about it.  Did you change it from the default?

Comment: Bitcode is iOS 9 though, so I don't understand why the linker is complaining.

Comment: Yeah it's confusing me. I'm gonna work on it more tomorrow. I need sleep lol. Thanks for your input tho! I really appreciate it

Comment: please paste at least some of those 'more errors', probably we could help then

Comment: So this is the error messages I get when I disable bitcode:Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADInterstitialAd", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iAD.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ADBannerView", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in iAD.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Ok so I fixed it I think! I disabled bitcode again and it worked!